# expected number of turns of the game

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

A board game is played on a hexagonal grid of 19 tiles. A 'traveler' token starts on the center tile. Each turn a die is rolled to determine what neighboring tile the traveler moves to (all six directions equally likely). The turn that the traveler leaves the board, the game ends. What is the expected number of turns of the game?

[image]

I have tried making a diagram for the problem ..but not sure if this is correct!!
[image]

Comment: I initially thought it could be easily solved using Markov chains ..but got stucked

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: A Markov approach:  there are only four active states in the game.  Either you are in the center, in the middle ring, on the outer ring in a cell with $2$ exits, or on the outer ring in a cell with $3$ exits.  Determine simple relations between the expectations starting in each of these states.

Comment: Added my approach in the question.

Comment: Your transition graph is not correct.  There are *two* distinguishable states at radius $2$.  Split that node into two, add all the transitions, and you'll be nearly done.

Comment: Yes, to accommodate that I have used symmetry and calculate probabilities of 5/12 and 3/12 respectively. Done this just to reduce no of nodes at point 2.

Comment: I cannot see how that will work because it depends *which* hexagon you're on to determine transitions.  You cannot simply average over them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the transition graph for the game:

[image]

Here is the transition matrix (where the sequence is 0, 1, 2a, 2b, 3):

$$M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1/6 & 1/3 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 0 \\
 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/2 \\
 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Read the row as "from node..." and the column as the "to node..."

Comment: Now just finding a vector with eigenvalue 1?

Comment: I found $(\frac{5}{34},\frac{5}{34},\frac{31}{136},\frac{29}{136},\frac{9}{136})$ to be a fixed point of the Markov chain.

Comment: @razivo:  Cannot be right.  Once the marker leaves (goes to radius = 3) the game is over.  The transition matrix must be from radius 3 to radius 3 with probability $1$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - How does the matrix lead to the expected no. of turns?  The only way I can think of right now is that $M^n_{0,3}$ gives the prob the game ended on or before turn $n$.  Then to calculate the expected value we can do an infinite sum.  That's all doable, but is there an easier way?  Perhaps some theorem or formula that I don't know / learned in school but have forgotten? :)

Comment: Yes, I think there will be an infinite sum.  You find the probability the mark "escapes" on step $n$, $p(n)$, then calculate ${\cal E}[n] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n p(n)$.